# Getting the last layer from a pretrained pytorch for transfer learning?

Tags: python, pytorch

This is what I did:

```
list(tmp.state_dict().keys())[-1].split('.')[0]
```

What is the proper way?
My goal is to replace the last layer for the purpose of transfer learning.

Answer (score 3):

You can simple follow these steps to get the last layer from a pretrained pytorch model:

- We can get the layers by using model.children().
- Convert this into a list by using a list() command on it.
- Remove the last layer by indexing the list.
- Finally, use the PyTorch function nn.Sequential() to stack this modified list together into a new model.

  `nn.Sequential(*list(model.children())[:-1])`

You can read more about this from [here](https://spandan-madan.github.io/A-Collection-of-important-tasks-in-pytorch/#SECTION-3---changing-last-layer,-deleting-last-layer,-adding-layers).

Comment: This does not return the same result as the query I put in the question?